# Pandas merge is doing cartesian product instead of inner join

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two identical frames and instead trying to inner join them, I get a cartesian product. Do you know what can cause that? The type of my columns is Int64.

```
df1 = 
operationid  siteid
  632126      66
  632126      66
```

```
df2 = 
operationid  siteid
  632126      66
  632126      66
```

when doing

```
df1.merge(df2 , how = 'inner' , on = [operationid , siteid ])
```

I expect

```
operationid  siteid
  632126      66
  632126      66
```

Instead, I get

```
   operationid  siteid
       632126      66
       632126      66
       632126      66
       632126      66
```

Comment: Assuming that you mean by _identical dataframes_ (`df1.eq(df2)=True`), what would be the purpose of merging them ? Maybe you want `pandas.concat` instead ? Anyway, can you share a reproducible example of the second dataframe and the matching expected output ?

Comment: df1 was obtained through a different query but looks exactly like df2.

the expected outcome is that df1.merge(df2) =
```operationid  siteid
  632126      66
  632126      66```

Comment: are the rows already aligned? then `out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`, else provide a better example

Answer (score 1):

The expected output you will get if you have unique records in df1 and df2.
Remove duplicate and try to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) function to drop the duplicates in one of your dataframes before you merge:

```py
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
desired_df = df1.merge(df2 , how = 'inner' , on = ['operationid' , 'siteid'])
print(desired_df)
```

Output:

```
   operationid  siteid
0       632126      66
1       632126      66
```

You can also choose to first check to see if both dataframes are the same, if `true` pick one of them and if `false` go ahead and merge them and it should output the same result:

```py
desired_df = pd.DataFrame()
if df1.equals(df2) == True:
    desired_df = df1
else:
    desired_df = df1.merge(df2 , how = 'inner' , on = ['operationid' , 'siteid'])
    
print(desired_df)
```